# Read from a file and input the formatted line to linked list. C

Tags: c, file-io, linked-list

I'm trying to read from a file, line by line, a formatted string and storing it in a linked list.

My typedef:

```
typedef struct s_deck {
    char name[16];
    int atk;
    int def;
    int cost;
    struct s_deck* next;
} card;
```

Example of a file I'm reading from:

```
Line 1: Name 4 4 5
Line 2: Name2 5 5 5
```

My function I'm trying to implement to do such a thing...

```
card *LoadDeck() {
    FILE* file = fopen("text", "r");
    if(file == NULL) {
        printf("unable to open file...\n");
    }
    char line[16];
    card* start = NULL;
    card* newest = NULL;
    card* previous = NULL;

    fgets(line, 15, file);
    card* newCard = malloc(sizeof(card));
    sscanf(line, "%s %d %d %d\n", newCard->name, &newCard->atk,
                &newCard->def, &newCard->cost);
    printf("Added:%s Attack:%d Defense:%d Cost:%d\n", newCard->name,    newCard->atk,
                newCard->def, newCard->cost);

    if (start == NULL) {
        start = LoadDeck(NULL);
        newest = start;
    } 
    else {
        newest = LoadDeck(newest);
    }

    if (previous != NULL) {
        previous->next = newCard;
    }
    fclose(file);
    return newCard;
}
```

So my issue I'm having is that it is an infinite loop where it reads the first line and the first line only. The printf I have is to see what its doing and... well its reading the line correctly but it just keeps doing it and never stops.

I don't know if its creating a linked list properly yet. I haven't gotten that far. I think I implemented it right but its so hard going off books only. I tried to find some questions here but their file they are reading from is much more complex than mine so I figured there should be a simpler way.

Comment: Note that `%s` format will read up to the first space if the name is something like "tank squadron" and the subsequent `%d` formats will fail. Alway check the return value of the `scanf` family. `if (sscanf(...) != 4)`

Comment: Do the input file really contain the `Line X: ` prefix?

Comment: As for your problem, you do know that when you open a file, the file position pointers are reset to the beginning? Use a *loop* instead of recursion.

Comment: Also, the expression `LoadDeck(newest)` doesn't do what you think it does. I'm not really sure *what* you think it does, but it definitely doesn't do that.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg no.. that was me simulating what line it was. so it just as Name and 4 ints

Comment: @JoachimPileborg ah... I didn't know it reset my pointer. I'll sort that out. and the LoadDeck(newest) is probably wrong as you say. I'll have to go back and read more. The example I learned all this from was setting up a linked list for taking user input from the stdin stream. So i'm trying to do it from file stream

Comment: @WeatherVane okay thanks. I didn't know of the space inbetween a string would cause that but I don't think any of them will have a space. But thanks for letting me know. I'll try to work around that if I do intend to have spaces in the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i know maybe i should put this in comment but sorry i don't have enough reputation to do it. Anyway i think your program loops endlessly because your *start* variable is always NULL, first call to the function is will lead to function to call itself after finding that *start == NULL* is true, the subsequent calls will always lead to an endless recursion because start is always NULL.
these lines you wrote is the *black hole*:

```
   if (start == NULL) {
    start = LoadDeck(NULL);
    newest = start; }
```

It doesn't assign anything to *start* variable, it just causes the endless recursion.

Comment: Thanks. That helped me figure out where the infinite loop was